# Capitalize bash variable

Tags: bash

I have the following line in bash:

```
echo "Manufacturer: $(echo ${family:-$name}|cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

I would like to capitalize the echoed string using the `${var^}` syntax but not sure how to add this to the current line. Can someone please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store above command's output in a variable using `command substitution`:

```
s=$(echo "Manufacturer: $(echo ${family:-$name}|cut -d' ' -f1)")
```

and then use:

```
echo "${s^^}"
```

to capitalize the string.

Answer (score 3):

two one liners

```
$ echo "watever" | awk '{print toupper($0)}'


$ echo "watever" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is handy here:

```
name=smith
family=""

echo "Manufacturer: $(sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\+/\U&/' <<< "${family:-$name}")"
```

```
Manufacturer: SMITH
```

If you only want to "title-case" it ("Manufacturer: Smith"), use `\u` instead of `\U`